# How to install GRUB Legacy (0.97) on an USB pen-drive from Ubuntu 20.04/21.10?

Tags: dd, mbr, grub-legacy

How to install GRUB Legacy (0.97) on an USB pen-drive from Ubuntu 20.04/21.10?

Ubuntu does no longer provide GRUB Legacy in their repository.
`grub-install` command will install GRUB 2.xx.

Probably I could look for an old bootable distro that ships GRUB 0.97 and `grub-install` from there, but maybe it can be done properly from my main OS.

[Old Ubuntu's GRUB 0.97 package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub/grub_0.97-29ubuntu68_amd64.deb) contains all the binary files for `stage1`, `fat_stage1_5` (I'm using FAT32), and `stage2` in `data.tar.xz/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-pc/`.
However running `grub-install` from that old Ubuntu package does not work.

How do I manually `dd` those files properly into the drive's MBR and following sectors?
I tried this (not to overwrite the partition table):

```
sudo dd if=stage1 of=/dev/sdX bs=446 count=1
```

What do I do with stages 1_5 and 2?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use an obsolete Grub? This is probably an X-Y problem.

Comment: I'm trying to chainload an iso image, which is impossible with GRUB2, but worked fine in GRUB 0.97. Here is a bug report for GRUB2: https://bugs.gentoo.org/385619

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to use that [old Ubuntu's package](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/grub/grub_0.97-29ubuntu68_amd64.deb) mentioned above to install GRUB 0.97:

1. On the pendrive's main partition create /boot/grub directory:

```
cd /mnt/sdX1
mkdir -p boot/grub
```

2. Copy all stages into it:

```
cd ${DATA_TAR_XZ}/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-pc
cp stage1 stage2 fat_stage1_5 /mnt/sdX1/boot/grub
```

3. Now run GRUB 0.97 shell:

```
cd ${DATA_TAR_XZ}/usr/sbin
sudo ./grub --device-map=/dev/null
```

4. And use it to setup GRUB for that pendrive:

```
device (hd0) /dev/sdX
geometry (hd0)
root (hd0,0)
setup --stage2=/boot/grub/stage2 --prefix=/boot/grub (hd0)
quit
```